# How to shift numpy slices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class like this

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top_left = (1,2)
        self.arr = np.reshape(np.arange(100), (10,10))
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        return self.arr[shifted(key, self.top_left)] = val
```

I want all the row indices appear in key to be shifted by 1 and all the column indices appear in key shifted by 2. Is it possible?

Edit:

Consider `a = A()` and `a.arr` to be

```
      [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Now when I set `a[0,0] = 5`, `a.arr` changes at index `(1,2)`. Because it gets shifted by `(1,2)`.
Again if I set `a[3:6, 3:6] = np.ones((3,3))` then a.arr looks like this:

```
     [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
      [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
      [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
      [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
      [40, 41, 42, 43, 44,  1,  1,  1, 48, 49],
      [50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  1,  1,  1, 58, 59],
      [60, 61, 62, 63, 64,  1,  1,  1, 68, 69],
      [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
      [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
      [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

because all the index in the key, gets shifted by (1,2).

Edit 2:
Currently I am storing the values in a separate array. And then putting this whole array, back to `arr`.

```py
self.arr2[key] = value
self.arr[self.top_left[1] : self.top_left[1] + self.shape[1],
         self.top_left[0] : self.top_left[0] + self.shape[1],
        ] = self.arr2
```

`self.shape` is shape of the editable window in `a.arr`

Comment: To shift an index, you can simply add the shifting value to your index ?

Comment: What happens when it is a slice? or a broadcast?

Comment: Create a minimal and reproducible example of your problem with an example input and the corresponding desired output, at the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: I made an edit. I hope it explains the problem.

Comment: @obchardon i have edited the post, is it good now?

Comment: The `+` symbol have the priority over `:`, you need to specify the priority with parenthesis: `arr((3:6)+1,(3:6)+2) = ones(4)` will work, for example.

Comment: doing `arr((1:2)+1, (3:4)+2)` returns error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array operate on builtin python `slice` or `tuple`.

`shifter` function decides what kind of index you passed.

```py
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top_left = (1,2)
        self.arr = np.reshape(np.arange(100), (10,10))

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.arr[self.shifter(key)] = val
    
    def shifter(self, key):
        if isinstance(key[0], slice):
            shift_func = self.shifted_slice
        else:
            shift_func = self.shifted_point
        return shift_func(key)

    def shifted_slice(self, key):
        row_slice, col_slice = key
        row_offset, col_offset = self.top_left
        return slice(row_slice.start + row_offset, row_slice.stop + row_offset), \
               slice(col_slice.start + col_offset, col_slice.stop + col_offset)
    
    def shifted_point(self, key):
        row_num, col_num = key
        row_offset, col_offset = self.top_left
        return row_num + row_offset, \
               col_num + col_offset
    
        
a = A()
a[0, 0] = 5
a[3:6, 3:6] = np.ones((3,3))

print(a.arr)
```

Outputs:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11,  5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44,  1,  1,  1, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  1,  1,  1, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64,  1,  1,  1, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```